# React – Import Stylesheet **only if** UserAgent is Mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, user-agent

Would like to import a mobile-specific stylesheet **ONLY IF** the UserAgent is mobile.

Integrated this UserAgent detection package, so we can successfully detect the UserAgent: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-useragent

Just don't know how to import mobile.css **ONLY WHEN** UserAgent is mobile. Thank you!

```
/* only load mobile.css if UserAgent is mobile */
import styles from '../../mobile.css';
```

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Yes we are.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional imports do exist! It's  in Webpack 2! Here's the [git repo](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) with examples and use cases

```
if (agent === whateverYouWant) {
    import('./mobile.css').then(() => {
       console.log("Imported mobile css");
    });
}
```

Additionally, you can also use `require` in conditionals.